# Would this method of mathematical induction still be correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Problem: Prove that $n^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ whenever $n$ is an odd positive integer.

Now according to many different solutions, the key is to rewrite the statement so that it applies to all positive integers and solve in two cases, one where n is odd and one where n is even.

Is is possible to solve it by, instead of proving $k+1$, you prove $k+2$, since $k$ is an odd, positive integer, and that implies that $k+2$ is the next odd, positive integer? When you solve for $k+2$, it would go along the lines of (skipping over the base case of $n=1$):

The inductive hypothesis would be that $k^2-1$ is divisible by $8$.

We plug in $k+2$ into $n^2-1$ and get $k^2+4k+4-1$

Rearrange to $(k^2-1) + 4(k+1)$

Now since $k$ is an odd, positive integer, $k+1$ must be an even positive integer. This means we can rewrite $k+1$ as $2m$, where $m$ is any positive integer.

Now, we have $(k^2-1) + 4(2m)$

Distribute to get $(k^2-1) + 8m$.

Using the result that for any integer $a$, where $a\neq0$, if $b$ is divisible by $a$, and $c$ is divisible by $a$, then $mb + nc$ is divisible by $a$ whenever $m,n$ are integers and the inductive hypothesis that $k^2-1$ is divisible by 8, this proves that for any positive odd integer, $n^2-1$ will be divisible by $8$.

TL;DR or the overall question: In the proof by mathematical induction, does $k+1$ have to be strictly $k+1$ with no alternative, or does it simply mean "the next element" when trying to prove that $P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1)$

Comment: Proving (works for k-->prove true for k+2) absolutely works in this case when you are looking at odd integers.

Comment: Your proof is valid.  It is a slight generalization of mathematical induction.  Whether or not to call it mathematical induction is a semantic question, not a mathematical one.

Comment: You could just as easily view it as being induction in $m$ where you write $n=2m+1$. :-)

Comment: 1. @NickPeterson's observation shows that your procedure is not merely a generalisation of mathematical induction (MI) but *essentially* MI (i.e., MI in disguise). 2. The conventional method rewrites (at the start) $n^2-1$ as $(2m-1)^2{-}1$ (for being odd), while your procedure rewrites (somewhere in the middle) $k+1$ as $2m$ (for being even).

Comment: This is mathematical induction. Not "essentially" nor "in disguise". Nor do I see any reasonable semantic question, though of course people are free to be obstinate about such matters. Mathematical induction is a much more flexible concept that the rigid $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ form we teach novices. It doesn't even have to be performed on natural numbers. Any well-founded set will do.